# Android fragments setRetainInstance(true) not works (Android support library)

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-support-library

I have a problem with saving fragment state. I try to use setRetainInstance, but cant make it work((( I change a state to 2 using button1, but after changing screen orientation i see 1 when pressing on button2. Where is my mistake?

```
public class TestFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setRetainInstance(true);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    private String state = "1";

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout, container, false);

        //button for changing state
        ((Button)view.findViewById(R.id.button1)).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                state = "2";
            }
        });

        //button for showing state
        ((Button)view.findViewById(R.id.button2)).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), state, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        return view;
    }

}
```

**EDIT**

Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

}
```

Activity layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <fragment
        android:name="ru.ee.TestFragment"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Fragment layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Change to 2" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Show" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Manifest XML:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="ru.ee.testfrag"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="ru.ee.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your fragment will only get re-used if you give the fragment an Id in the layout, change

```
<fragment
    android:name="ru.ee.TestFragment"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
```

to be

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/a_fragment"
    android:name="ru.ee.TestFragment"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Searching endlessly for this kind of stuff is really bad for my health. I'm so glad it's over!

Comment: If saveInstanceState() really doesn't take effect without a fragment ID in the layout, and fails silently otherwise, that really ought to be stated in the documentation for saveInstanceState()!

Answer (score 0):

There isn't anything wrong with the code you posted.  If you have the fragment implemented correctly, it should be giving you a state of 2.  Maybe you could post your activity and xml files.  There error must be somewhere else.

Comment: i add activity and xml codes, please look at it if you have some time. i have already look at this code a hundred times, but cant understand where is my mistake(((